# Ionic - File download not showing up in the correct download folder

Tags: android, react-native, ionic-framework, download

I am using an Ionic React App with Capacitor.

I have following code:

```
      const filePath = File.externalRootDirectory + "Download/" + name; 
    
      HTTP.downloadFile("https://url.com/uploads/"+match.params.id+"/"+name, {}, {}, filePath).then(response => {
        // prints 200
        console.log('success block...', JSON.stringify(response));
    
        }).catch(err => {
        // prints 403
        console.log('error block ... ', err.status);
        // prints Permission denied
        console.log('error block ... ', err.error);
        });
```

The file is saved to this location:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/file.xlsx
```

It shows up in the internal storage download folder, but not in the "shortcut" Download folder and not in the current files. I want it to show up in the marked folder:
[image]

Comment: the downloads folder you are showing open it and check it is in sd card or internal storage

Comment: And after rebooting your device?

Comment: @blackapps I just rebooted my device, but the files are still not in the marked folder

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I have no SD-Card in my device

Comment: Which Android version on used device? The screendump is of which app?

Comment: @blackapps I am using a Samsung Anroid 10 device and the screenshot is of the samung "My files" app.